Set up Cmake Cpack to use a debian/rules?
I have some C++ code for a Linux service, for which I've used CPack to create the .deb package, which builds fine then I run make package_deb:
install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION bin
)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.service
        DESTINATION /usr/lib/systemd/system
)
# ...
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "The Maintainer") #required
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_FILE_NAME DEB-DEFAULT)
string(REPLACE "_" "-" CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
set (CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake")
include(CPack)
# ...
add_custom_target(package_deb
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND}" "-C" "$<CONFIGURATION>" "--config" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BundleConfig.cmake"
  COMMAND /bin/bash ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/post_package_deb.sh
)

The problem is, installing the package does not automatically enable and start the service; this is discussed/answered here: Automatically enable systemd services installed using deb? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange :

You need 3 things: rules to contain dh $@ --with systemd, control to contain Build-Depends: dh-systemd, postinst to contain #DEBHELPER# and a reasonable current build system [...]
I've worked around the problem by calling dh_systemd_enable (to make the service run by default) and dh_systemd_start (to actually start it after installation) manually from the override_dh_auto_install target in rules, so it looks like this:
%:
    dh $@ --with-systemd

override_dh_auto_install:
    dh_auto_install
    dh_systemd_enable || true
    dh_systemd_start || true


Cool - but how do I refer to debian/rules in a Cpack setup in CMakeLists.txt?
I have noted that CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER ends up as Maintainer:  field in an autogenerated control file after my make package_deb has run - but what do I do about rules file, so I can to the above overrides? I cannot see much (Ctrl-F "/rules" - 0 results) in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/CPackDeb.html ( I've also seen there exists something called https://gitlab.kitware.com/debian/dh-cmake , but I cannot tell if it is related to/can help with my problem ).

Well, just found this: https://github.com/ABruines/CPackDebHelper

A CMake module that allows your project to use the debhelper tool suite to assist the CPack DEB generator.
The example ./CMakeLists.txt contains a small project that uses the module.

... and the example https://github.com/ABruines/CPackDebHelper/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt has code such as:
# ...
#
# Set CPackDebHelper vars:
#

# Required. The directory that contains the files listed in CPACK_DEBHELPER_INPUT
set(CPACK_DEBHELPER_INPUT_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/debian")

# Required. List of input files that require processing by the debhelpers.
# ...
set(CPACK_DEBHELPER_INPUT
  control.in
  ${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}.changelog.in
# ...

# Optional. Set the debhelper compatability level, if left unset CPackDebHelper
# sets this to 12.
unset(CPACK_DEBHELPER_COMPAT)
# ...

So, I guess this can help - and there's probably no native facility for this in CMake (at least, CMake 3.28 which I use)...
